# Argument not accepted even though it is of the correct type

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am getting the following error when I try and pass `this` as an argument to a function. `this` is an `EquipmentNavigation` class instance

> Argument 5: cannot convert from 'EquipmentNavigation [Assembly-CSharp-Editor, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]' to 'EquipmentNavigation [Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]' (CS1503) [Assembly-CSharp-Editor, Assembly-CSharp-Editor]

As you can see, it cannot convert from `EquipmentNavigation` to `EquipmentNavigation` which makes no sense.

I am sure the argument signature is correct.

Here is my version info:

```
Version: 1.38.1
Commit: b37e54c98e1a74ba89e03073e5a3761284e3ffb0
Date: 2019-09-11T13:31:32.854Z
Electron: 4.2.10
Chrome: 69.0.3497.128
Node.js: 10.11.0
V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 17.7.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seemed I just had to reopen Unity to load the files, since I was creating/moving files in Visual Studio and not in Unity. For some reason the Visual Studio features seem to break if I don't have Unity open.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at that error message, they're not quite the same type:

```
'EquipmentNavigation [Assembly-CSharp-Editor, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]'
```

to

```
'EquipmentNavigation [Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]'
```

They're from different assemblies. (The top one includes `editor` in the name)